# ruby find entry in array

Tags: ruby, arrays, math

I have some array

```
[0,1,0,1,0]
[0,0,1,1,0]
[1,1,0,1,1]
```

and some mask

```
[1,0]
[0,1]
```

What approach I should use to find sequence by mask?

Sample array can be any size and mask can be any size too

I need some strategy or math solution

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.  In the above example what should the output be?

Comment: something like x=1, y=0 in this case, position of top left corner will be enought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite understand the question, but is this what you're looking for:

```
a = [0,1,0,1,0]
b = [1,0]
x = a.each_cons(b.length).map { |i| i == b}.index(true)
```

You can also replace `index(true)` with `first`.

Comment: Thanks, its work well for 3 elements
`x = a.each_cons(b.length).map do |aa|
  aa == b
end.index(true)`

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for correcting me too. I was assuming that the array will always have 2 members by using `[i, j]`. ;-) I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

This problem lends itself to use of the `Matrix` class, particularly for the use of the method [Matrix#minor](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-minor).

For given "main" and "masking" matrices, the method below extracts, for each row of the main matrix, all sequences of sub-matrices for which each element in the sequence equals the masking matrix.

**Code**

```
require 'matrix'

def find_sequences(arr, mask)
  arr_rows  = arr.size
  arr_cols  = arr.first.size
  @mask_rows  = mask.size
  @mask_cols  = mask.first.size
  m_arr   = Matrix[*arr]
  @m_mask = Matrix[*mask]

  (arr_rows-@mask_rows+1).times.with_object([]) do |i,seq|
    j = 0
    while j <= arr_cols-@mask_cols do
      len = row_sequence(m_arr.minor(i,@mask_rows,j,arr_cols-j))
      if len > 0
        seq << [i,j,len]
        j += len * @mask_cols + 1
      else
        j += 1
      end
    end
  end
end

def row_sequence(msub)
  len = 0
  0.step(by: @mask_cols, to: msub.column_count-@mask_cols) { |j|
    (msub.minor(0,@mask_rows,j,@mask_cols) == @m_mask) ?
      (len += 1) : (return len) }
  len
end
```

**Example**

```
arr =  [[0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0],
        [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0],
        [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
        [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1],
        [1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1]]

mask = [[1,0],
        [0,1]]

find_sequences(arr, mask)
  #=>  row col len
  #   [[0,  1,  1],
  #    [0,  6,  1],
  #    [1,  3,  3],
  #    [2,  0,  4],
  #    [3,  1,  2]]
```